# Универсализация обработки исключений

Tags: c++, ооп, исключения

Есть у меня много методов, которые имеют такой вид

```cpp
try {
   .....
} catch (const MyException & e) {
  return HandleError(e);
} catch (const std::exception & e) {
  return HandleError(e);
}
```

И функции обработки

```cpp
HRESULT HandleError(const std::exception & ex, HRESULT code) {
    SetErrorInfo(ex.what());
    return code;
}

HRESULT HandleError(const std::exception & ex) {
    return HandleError(ex, E_UNEXPECTED);
}

HRESULT HandleError(const MyException & ex) {
    return HandleError(ex, ex.code);
}
```

Вопрос: а нельзя ли сократить catch блок до такого вида

```cpp
try {
   .....
} catch (const std::exception & e) {
  return HandleError(e);
}
```

А в самой функции уже принимать решение о том, что это за исключение и что с ним делать

```cpp
HRESULT HandleError(const std::exception & ex) {
    if (ex is MyException)  // нужен оператор проверки класса-наследника
        return HandleError(ex, dynamic_cast<MyException)(ex).code);
    else
        return HandleError(ex, E_UNEXPECTED);
}
```

Потому что нужно проверять несколько разных исключений из разных библиотек и у каждого есть свой код ошибки. Не хочется вставлять лесенку идентичных catch. Макросы пока не рассматриваю

Comment: `dynamic_cast` над указателем проверит класс наследника.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, `dynamic_cast` в помощь. Имея `const std::exception &e`, делаете вот так:

```
if (auto m = dynamic_cast<const MyException *>(&e)) {...}
```

Еще можно в `HandleError` ничего не передавать, и в ней делать `try {throw;}` и лесенку из `catch`-ей. Тогда в вызывающем коде можно просто писать `catch (...) {return HandleError();}`.

Если беспокоит возможность получить вылет, если вызвать такую функцию вне catch, то посмотрите в сторону [`std::current_exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception) - это замена `throw;`, но позволяет проверить, есть ли сейчас исключение.

Comment: а причем тут dynamic_cast?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Ну. Можно сделать `catch (std::exception &e)`, потом `if (MyException *m = dynamic_cast<MyException *>(&e)) {...} else {...}`.

Comment: Ну это же нужно вписать в ответ(я так думаю)...

Answer (score 3):

Это делается посредством выбрасывания и повторного перехвата текущего исключения в другом контексте:

```
try
{
   .....
}
catch (...)
{
   return Handle_Error();
}

HRESULT Handle_Error(void) noexcept
{
    try
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch (const MyException & e)
    {
        return e.code;
    }
    catch (const std::exception & e)
    {
        return E_UNEXPECTED;
    } 
    catch (...)
    {
        return E_UNEXPECTED;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если какой-то раззява вызовет Handle_Error() без активного исключения, случится std::terminate().

Comment: Я бы назвал это  ружьем Чехова-Мерфи-Голуба - "Если в первом акте программы на C++ на стене  висит ружье, оно в неожиданный момент  выстрелит по ногам самым необъяснимым  и драматичным образом."

Comment: @gbg Не зачем так драматизировать. Проблем будет не больше, чем с вызовом любой другой функции в неподходящем для этого месте. Скорее даже меньше, так как в таком сценарии программа будет сразу прервана. А тенденция к неправильному использованию такой специфичной функции - тем более меньше.